# CSS - position: absolute; - auto height

Tags: css

I am having a problem with some div's

The outer div has a min-height, but the inner divs are all varying heights. Because the inner divs are absolute positioned, they do not affect the outer divs height. Is there a way to make these inner divs affect the height of the outer div?

The reason I am styling these divs with position:absolute is so that they all start at the top of the container div.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no way for absolutely positioned child elements to affect the height of their statically, or relatively positioned parent elements using only CSS.  Either:

- Reorganize so that the child elements remain in the document flow
- Use JavaScript on load of the page to set the height of the parent to the height of the largest child

This issue is common in fade-in/fade-out JavaScript slideshows, and from what I've seen either 1) the height of the parent container needs to be defined or 2) the parent container's height is set dynamically for each slide.

Comment: To anyone choosing to use JavaScript, please keep in mind that you should probably recalculate the height of the parent when the window is resized. 

Personally I would encourage a pure CSS solution, to avoid having to worry about such cases. Though clearly that causes different problems, like spending over seven years attempting to find an answer to a question with only 18 upvotes... +1

Answer (score 19):

I recently had this problem with a fade in/out CSS transition slideshow, and ended up solving it by giving the first child element `position: relative;` and the others `position: absolute; top:0; left: 0;` which ensures that the containers height is the same as the height of first element. Since my CSS transition slideshow uses the opacity property the container dimensions never changes during the course of the slideshow.

Alas, since I also needed to supply a javascript fallback for older browsers I had to set the container height for these browsers anyway (because of jQuerys fadeIn/fadeOut actually setting `display: none;` I would guess).

Comment: This truly saved my day. I was trying to figure out a how-to achieve one layout for 2 days and finally stumbled upon this answer. God bless you!

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `display: inline-table, height: auto;`  .. it works for me

Answer (score 1):

Here is a long overdue cross-browser solution to your problem. No more static `width`, no more `em` hack.

```
<style>
  /* clearfix */
  .container:after {
    content: '';
    display: table;
    clear: left;
  }

  .page {
    float: left; /* display side-by-side */
    width: 100%; /* be as wide as parent */
    margin-right: -100%; /* take up no width */
  }
</style>

<div class="container">
  <div class="page"></div>
  <div class="page"></div>
</div>
```

After searching for a solution to this problem for so long, I am baffled to see how simple it is. Granted, the `.page` elements are not absolutely positioned. However, all the same goals can be achieved through this method, with almost no pain or sacrifice.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/eqe2muhv/

This also works for inline-blocks, of course. Though you might need to set the `font-size` or `letter-spacing` of the container to `0`. I would also recommend using `vertical-align: top` on the `.page`, to simulate a regular block element.

Here's a demo: https://jsfiddle.net/dzouxurs/8/

Comment: Dug this up again, still proves useful. While I am at it, here is an animated demo: https://jsfiddle.net/b92kmcus/

Answer (score 0):

I think you should position them relatively and just change "vertical-align" to "top" in the interior divs.  Then you won't have the issue of messing with abs divs.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply float the divs if you want them to be on the same horizontal plane.

Answer (score 0):

i've done this task without any `JS`. Only, by CSS:

```
.frame {
   max-height: calc(100vh - 283px); // 283px gives me some space at the botoom of the frame
}
```

Comment: you are missing the property there... width or height

Answer (score 0):

Maybe u can try `max-height: calc(100% - 50%);` it will work if the content that should be in the middle of the screen/div is super short/small.

```
position:absolute;
top:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
width:auto;
height:auto
max-height: calc(100% - 50%);
...etc...
```

Answer (score -3):

Test `display: inline-block` on the element that need auto height.