# How to make parent container resize to child container correctly without using min-height

Tags: css, css-float

**Example of the problem here: http://jsfiddle.net/uq0zzf7t/**

I have the follow css code:

```
.wizard
{
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard > .steps
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}

.wizard > .content
{
    display: block;
    margin: 0.5em;
    position: relative;
    width: auto;
    min-height: 35em;
    overflow: visible;
}

.wizard > .actions
{   
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    text-align: right;
    width: 100%;
}
```

And my wizard form looks like this:
[image: Image pic]

However, if I remove min-height: 35em from .wizard > .content, I get the following picture

[image: Image pic 2]

My goal is to make the actions container appear on the bottom of content container without using min-height. This will be useful if I have content that is bigger than 35em and it overflows the content container.

Example of where the children of content does not fit:

[image: Overflow gone wrong]

All of the containers have clearfix applied from bootstrap

Here is an example of the problem in jsfiddle using demo code:

http://jsfiddle.net/uq0zzf7t/

Comment: using jquery on document ready, to get ur ".content" height and then set ".wizzard" height with ur content height, have u try it?

Comment: share HTML too, otherwise it's not possible for us to find out the issue.

Comment: Jquery works but I was hoping there was a CSS fix somewhere. The html is a autogenerated from the jquery-steps plug-in and an html form. The basic structure is <form> <div class="steps clearfix>...</div> <div class="content clearfix">...</div> <div class="actions clearfix>...</div> </form>

Comment: Updated it with jsfiddle code here: jsfiddle.net/uq0zzf7t

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`absolute` positioned elements do not have auto height. Is there any reason you have given `position: absolute` to  `.wizard > .content > .body`?

If not then remove that, and the `div` will auto size according to its content.

Explanation in this SO [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822685/1520671)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `height: auto;` property in your parent class.

Have a look on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Kyle_Sevenoaks/STSjm/).

Comment: Hi, I updated the post with demo code here: http://jsfiddle.net/uq0zzf7t/ . Height:auto doesn't seem to work here