# position:fixed messing with keyframes animation

Tags: css, animation, position, fixed

On my website, a keyframes animation is supposed to tint in blue an image. But the position:fixed of the property making this very same image responsive seems to mess with the keyframes.

If I remove the position:fixed, the blue tint transition occurs. But when I put it back, the tint transition is white instead of blue.

For the codepen : [click here](http://codepen.io/zaky/pen/epmWWR)

Is there any way to get both of these properties to work along ?

Here's the code :

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="hover-min.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" />
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:400,900' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <script type="application/javascript" src="dist/js/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>       
    <script type="application/javascript" src="dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="background.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
 </head>

<body>
    <div id="opacity"> <!-- DIV containing the image supposed to turn blue -->
        <img src="http://www.nexusyouthsummit.org/wp-content/uploads/2013/09/nyc-fisheye-20121.jpg" alt="" class="nyc" />
    </div>      
</body>
</html>

/* CSS */
img.nyc {
    *position:fixed; /* property messing with the blue tint transition, rendering it white unless I remove it */
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:-1;
}

#opacity {
    background-color: #428BCA;
    display:inline-block;
}
#opacity img {
    height : 300px;
    opacity: 0.5;
    -webkit-animation: animation 2s linear;
    -moz-animation: animation 2s linear;
    -ms-animation: animation 2s linear;
    -o-animation: animation 2s linear;
    animation: animation 2s linear;
}

@-webkit-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@-moz-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 5;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 5;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@-o-keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 1;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
@keyframes animation{
    from{
        opacity: 5;
    }
    to{
        opacity: 0.5;
    }
}
```

Comment: the codepen link is not there

Comment: Sorry, it is now. :)

Comment: what if you move the positioning to `#opacity`?

Comment: Well, both work, which is good, thanks. But the image is cropped now.

Comment: The picture, used as a background image, has its bottom cropped within the browser's window. But when it's in full screen, the entire image appears, no crop.

Comment: Ok so I fixed the cropped image issue by... resizing the image itself. It works perfectly fine now. I'd like to upvote your comments for your help, but it seems like you need to post a proper answer so I can do so.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the fixed positioning to `#opacity`:

```
#opacity {
  position: fixed;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

"#opacity" doesn't know how big it should become after you set it's child to position:absolute or position:fixed.
If you set

```
#opacity {
    height : 300px;
    width: 660px;
    position: fixed;
    background-color: #428BCA;
    display:inline-block;
}
```

it will work again.

You will likely need some js-code to crop the parent to it's biggest child.(https://stackoverflow.com/a/2822685/5191731)

Comment: The blue tint transition only occurs in the dimensions you set in the width and height of your code. To make it occurs on the whole image, I had to set with and height to auto. 

Now the issue isn't the blue tint transition, but the image cropped at the bottom when it's not in full screen.