# CSS Parent to adjust based on content that is absolutely positioned

Tags: html, css

I would like my parent `div` to adjust its size based on the content but my problem is the contents are using `position: absolute;` therefore rendering the parent `div` as if it doesn't have any content.

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ka85rxu/) and the corresponding code:

#### HTML

```
<p>Gray box adjusts based on the green box's size.</p>
<div class="box">
  <div class="block"></div>
</div>

<p>Gray box doesn't adjust because the green box is absolutely positioned.</p>
<div class="box">
  <div class="absolute block"></div>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.box {
  padding: 5px;
  background-color: #888888;
}

.block {
  width: 60px;
  height: 60px;
  background-color: #65da98;
}

.absolute {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50px;
}
```

I guess what I want to take from this question are the following:

- What are my possible solutions?
- Which of those solutions would be best if we're to take into account cross-browser friendliness?

Comment: Have you seen this thread? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2822537/css-postion-absolute-auto-height

Comment: @PascalGoldbach Ok, thanks I'll take a look.

Comment: Why is it absolute? You could do `position: relative` and that would allow positioning while leaving behind a "shadow element" where it used to be.

Comment: @4castle because then it would affect the other contents' position like on the following [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ka85rxu/2/). Please note that I have other blocks as content that are also positioned absolutely.

Comment: @4castle Here's another [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/4ka85rxu/3/) where I used `relative` and `display: inline-block;` on the blocks but the same problem happens.

Comment: Can you perhaps show a fiddle that has all of the characteristics that you need? Then we can suggest solutions from there. Without seeing the bigger picture it's hard to know what will work. At some point you may need to consider JavaScript or a fixed height.

Comment: @4castle Here's what I'm doing: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2UJcZ/417/). Ignore the fact that the nodes can be dragged around because I disabled that functionality. In this case I am using `min-height` but I really don't want to do that as the chart can be vertically taller than what I have here depending on the number of descendants.